# Why SlugField generates these indexes?

Tags: django, django-south

I have a model with a SlugField. And, after I ran south migrate, I saw 2 indexes, as mentioned below , in Postgres. What is the use of the second index?

```
CREATE INDEX school_student_slug
ON school_student
USING btree
(slug);

CREATE INDEX school_student_slug_like
ON school_student
USING btree
(slug varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield `db_index` is set to `True` for `SlugField`